# Passing a reference of a function as a callback returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have the following code:

```
var BE = BE || {};

BE.UiEvents = function(s) {
    this.collapseForm = $(s.collapseForm);
    this.showmenu = $(s.showmenu);
    this.searchTrigger = $(s.searchTrigger);
    this.arrowDownIcon = s.arrowDownIcon;
    this.arrowUpIcon = s.arrowUpIcon;
    this.datePicker = $(s.datePicker);

    return this;
};

BE.UiEvents.prototype.show_menu = function(e) {
    console.log(this.collapseForm);
};
```

inside "document.ready" I do this:

```
var t = new BE.UiEvents({
    collapseForm: '.collapse-form',
    showmenu: '#showmenu>span',
    searchTrigger: '.default-orange.search-again',
    arrowDownIcon: 'fa-chevron-down',
    arrowUpIcon: 'fa-chevron-up',
    datePicker: 'input[name=dateStartDatePickerWidget]'
});

t.show_menu();

$('#showmenu').off('click').on('click', t.show_menu);
```

when I call "t.show_menu" it outputs the console.log statement.
However "on click" it returns undefined.

Comment: is it what are you looking for? -> [***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/1572/)

Comment: yes but why I can't pass only the reference? 't.show_menu' as oppose to call the function?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, probably you are losing `this` context somewhere.